# Asp.Net MVC 5 with oracle connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have an issue with connection , on my MVC 5 application, the issue is when i change connection string of my application from online connection to local connection, and tries to log in to the application it throws the following exception:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

and here's the stack trace:

> at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String
>   hashedPassword, String password)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(String
>   hashedPassword, String providedPassword)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<VerifyPasswordAsync>d__3e.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at DECC.Controllers.AccountController.d__15.MoveNext() in
>   D:\DECC_old\DECC\DECC\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 103

and here's my old connections :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mydb.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ssss))); User Id=user;Password=pass;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myDb.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ssss)));PASSWORD=pass;USER ID=user&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and here's the new connection :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE))); User Id=DECC_DBA;Password=DECC_DBA;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));PASSWORD=DECC_DBA;USER ID=DECC_DBA&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Update :** 
here's my log in code

```
    try
    {
        result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, shouldLockout: true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes i am using entity framework EDMX

Comment: Have you using ASP.NET Identity? Seems that you need to remove Identity tables from EDMX file (`AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUserClaims`, `AspNetUserLogins` and `AspNetUserRoles` table).

Comment: I am using asp.net identity oracle https://github.com/arichika/AspNet.Identity.Oracle,
I don't have those tables on my db

Comment: In Oracle library provided, each Identity tables use these naming conventions: `ANID2USERS`, `ANID2ROLES`, `ANID2USERLOGINS`, `ANID2USERROLES` & `ANID2USERCLAIMS`. Can you provide example of login code which throwing exception there?

Comment: The `PasswordSignInAsync` method works fine when testing Identity example project with EDMX, thus `UserManager` class should be the problem source which default Identity's `PasswordHasher` may be used instead of using customized one (they're providing different Base64 hashing mechanism indeed). Can you provide clues about `UserManager` instance then?